Deducing existence and uniqueness of a solution from an inequality for the max of norms
In the following, I am referring to this paper, p. 14, line (3.14):
It is said that from
$$
\max\left(\sup_{n\geq 0}\Vert f^n\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2,\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta t\Vert f^n-\rho^n M\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\right)\leq\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\tag{3.14}
$$
one can deduce existence and uniqueness of a solution $(f_{ij}^n)_{i\in\mathcal{I},j\in\mathcal{J},n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the scheme (3.10) which is given by
$$
\varepsilon\Delta x_i\Delta v_j (f_{ij}^{n+1}-f_{ij}^n)+\Delta t \left(F_{i+\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}-F_{i-\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}\right)=\frac{\Delta t}{\varepsilon}\Delta x_i\Delta v_j (\rho_i^{n+1}M_j-f_{ij}^{n+1}).
$$
Here,
$$F_{i+\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}=v_j\frac{f_{i+1,j}^{n+1}+f_{i,j}^{n+1}}{2}\Delta v_j,\qquad F_{i-\frac{1}{2},j}^{n+1}=v_j\frac{f_{i-1,j}^{n+1}+f_{i,j}^{n+1}}{2}\Delta v_j$$
denote numerical fluxes.
The given argument is:


Since scheme (3.10) is a finite dimensional linear system, we deduce from (3.14) the uniqueness of a solution, and then the existence.


My question: Why does (3.14) imply uniqueness and existence?
My main problem is to see the existence.

Here is what I have reached so far:
1. As to uniqueness:
I assumed that $(f_{ij}^n)$ and $(g_{ij}^n)$ are two distinct solutions and set  $(h_{ij}^n)$ as $h_{ij}^n:=f_{ij}^n-g_{ij}^n$. The idea is to show that $(h_{ij}^n)$ is again a solution and, moreover, it is zero.
Plugging this into the equation, my computations show that $(h_{ij}^n)$ is indeed a solution of (3.10). Thus, I can apply (3.14) to it. If I am not mistaken, $\Vert h^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2=\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\vert h_{ij}^0\vert^2\gamma_j\Delta x_i\Delta v_j=0$ since the initial data $f_{ij}^0$ and $g_{ij}^0$ should be the same for both solutions, so that $h_{ij}^0=f_{ij}^0-g_{ij}^0=0$ for all $i,j$. I therefore get
$$
\max\left(\sup_{n\geq 0}\Vert h^n\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2,\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta t\Vert h^n-\rho^n M\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\right)\leq\Vert h^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2=0.
$$
Now, since both arguments of the maximum function are non-negative, this should imply
$$
\sup_{n\geq 0}\Vert h^n\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2=0
$$
which means that
$$
\Vert h^n\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2=\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{I}\times\mathcal{J}}\vert h_{ij}^n\vert^2\gamma_j\Delta x_i\Delta v_j=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad h_{ij}^n=0
$$
for all $n\geqslant 0$ since $\gamma_j>0, \Delta x_i >0$ and $\Delta v_j>0$ for all $i,j$.
Hence, the solutions $(f_{ij}^n)$ and $(g_{ij}^n)$ coincide. Consequently, if a solution to (3.10) exists, it is unique.
2. As to existence:
(3.10) is a finite dimensional square linear system. Aren't uniqueness and existence equivalent in this case?
